# Linux kernel build fails with sed: can't read modules.order: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling, make, error-handling

I am trying to build Linux Kernel for the first time and I am facing below issue while trying to *make modules_install*

```
sed: can't read modules.order: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:1483: __modinst_pre] Error 2
```

So I went and reran *make -j4* and checked it's exit code suing echo $? it returns exit code 2

```
dejani@dejani-linux:~/Documents/linux-6.0.7$ make -j4
  DESCEND objtool
  DESCEND bpf/resolve_btfids
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:1852: certs] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CHK     kernel/kheaders_data.tar.xz

dejani@dejani-linux:~/Documents/linux-6.0.7$ echo $?
2
```

Can anyone help me out here? How do I get it to print errors/warnings/stack traces?

Comment: Where is that kernel source from? What steps did you take after unpacking/installing the source? The error message is right there in the output: `No rule to make target 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'`.